# MySQL how to get a specific row from a table

Tags: mysql

I have a database with the fields:  `land, zone, domestic`. And I want to get all this info out depending on what land the user chooses. So I figured I do this: 
`SELECT * FROM myDB WHERE land=Norway` (Norway is a stored country).

But I get the error `unknown column Norway`. Is this because it cant find Norway or what seems to be the problem?

Comment: Missing the quotes for string

Comment: Did you mean this? `SELECT * FROM myDB WHERE land = 'Norway'`?

Comment: `myDB` is your table name, right? If it's your *Database* name you should take note of [SaggingRufuses Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42366991/3536236).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you aren't specifying a table name try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM MyDB.MyTable 
WHERE land = 'Norway'
```

Also note that string Norway is in single quotes

Comment: The problem was the quotes. Thx!

Answer (score 2):

You missed the single quotes before and after the country name that you've used, as per my comment on the question earlier!

```
SELECT * FROM myDB WHERE land = 'Norway'
```

The above query works on the assumption that your table is actually named as `myDB`

Answer (score 1):

You need  quotes around literal

```
SELECT * FROM myDB.tablename WHERE land='Norway';
```

(and a proper tablename)  otherwise  your value is used  like a column name and give your the error Unknown column Norway.

Answer (score 0):

You are query using a where clause that confront a column with text. So to compare you have to tell to the dbms the value to match  . Using only Norway it doesn't understand that you are asking for the row with Norway value. Using 'Norway' you are telling "hey dbms here you are your text to confront". I hope that I'm to help.

Answer (score -1):

You can use ` marks for choosing columns/tables, so you should do something like

```
SELECT `column1`,`column2` FROM `tablename` WHERE `column`="value"
```

Comment: `Using single quotes for string literals is defined (and required) by the SQL standard`. [reference](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11321508/3536236) . While double quotes will work (and this surprised me) and are technically not wrong, it's not at all best practise.